# Image segmentation in open-source software

Tags: open-source-gis, software-recommendations, image-segmentation, image-analysis

For an analysis of several multilayer raster files I want to perform some kind of image segmentation (multi-resolution, ...) to extract polygon object of similar raster properties. I know that Trimble's eCognition is quite useful fot this kind of tasks. However I am trying to find a script based solution, since there are multiple (some 20s) of rasters the image segmentation schould be performed on.

I personally prefer the script languages R or Python.

Comment: Are you working with singleband data or multiband data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Python, there are very few option for free source RS based image segmentation. I'll suggest two,

- **[Orfeo Toolbox](https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/):** Probably the best free alternative of eCognition. It has quite a few [segmentation module](https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/SoftwareGuide/SoftwareGuidech17.html#x46-24700017). Its available inside Python, in QGIS; even has its own gui alternative called [Monteverdi](http://otbcb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Monteverdi.html).
- [**RSGISLib:**](http://www.rsgislib.org/index.html) Another Python library which also has a decent set of [segmentation module](http://www.rsgislib.org/rsgislib_segmentation.html). RSGISLib binaries are currently available for Linux and osx users only.

If it's not remote sensing I'll suggest [OpenCV](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_table_of_contents_imgproc/py_table_of_contents_imgproc.html).

Comment: More information about the segmentation and object based classification within RSGISLib is available in the following open access paper: http://www.mdpi.com/2072-4292/6/7/6111

Answer (score 3):

For segmentation, while you can probably go into the detailed statistical properties of the data (particularly for SAR), it is often a good start to assume that these are normal images/stacks of images, so standard image processing segmentation approaches will  often  work well. All you need to do is to read in the data as numpy arrays using e.g. GDAL/rasterio.

Once you have the data available, [scikit-image](https://scikig-image.org/) is an actively developed image processing library with lots of [useful segmentation](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/index.html#segmentation-of-objects) algorithms and tools to help you understand the results.

Answer (score 0):

**Saga** is another option, to carry out processes without programming, it has tools for segmentation including watershed, region growing, OBIA and is easy to use